# Asking question about event that happened some minutes ago

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, perfect-constructions

If someone giving me order on the phone and then after 1-2 minutes he/she comes in front of me, how I can ask him that he/she gives the order on phone or they come without giving order on the phone?

Is it can be like "Have you already give the order?" or "Did you give the order?"?

Comment: Perahps, a natural way would be, "Have you ordered?" or "Have you already ordered?".

Comment: Although, in your question you've written, "If someone giving me order on the phone".  You might find that looking at the past, future and present tenses of verbs, generally, will help you find find the appropriate phrases.  In your question, "If someone is giving me an order over the phone" would seem more natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did you already **place** *your* order?
>   Have you already **placed** *your* order?

In this kind of situation, I would use the verb *place* as it is more specific than *give*. See [**place**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/place):

> 23. to arrange for a desired handling, treatment, or allocation of"   ⇒ *to place a shipment, to place a child for adoption*"